# Index not being used for logical operation

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning

We have a MySQL table with a few million rows. We have set of users identified by a flag which int value. We are facing a problem that mysql is not using index. For example, following query is very slow:

```
select email, flag from usertable where (flag&0x40)!=0 limit 10;
```

Following is explain

```
> explain select email, flag from usertable where (flag&0x40)!=0 limit 10;
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------      +------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | usertable | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 8331189 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

and here is indexes

```
> show index from usertable;
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| usertable |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | uid         | A         |     8331189 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| usertable |          0 | email_index |            1 | email       | A         |     8331189 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| usertable |          1 | flagindex   |            1 | flag        | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

As I understand, logical & operation might be prohibiting use of index. What could be the solution in that case?

Comment: Is there no other way then to use an integer as a flag? From the cardinality of 18 I guess that there are not that many unique 'usertypes'. Also are all 8.3 million users still active and 'interesting'?

Comment: Is `flag` an int? Is it used instead of `BIT` columns? How many rows does the query return?

Comment: Also, edit the question and add the output of `show create table usertable;`. Far more useful that `show indexes`.

Comment: @Marco - Suppose you have a set of integers and you want to know which ones are divisible by 7.  How would you do it?  Effectively, you need to check each integer.  That's the complexity of checking bit(s) of integers.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using an integer column `flag` where a series of `BIT` columns or - even better - an intersection table should be used.

The index on `(flag)` is effectively useless for the condition `where (flag & 0x40) != 0`. Even if it was used, the whole index would have to be scanned first, then all the values computed (with `& 0x40`) and compared to `0`. After that, the matching rows would have to be fetched from the table, resulting in multiple, even millions of seeks. The optimizer is clever enough to do a simple - and fast but still rather slow - whole table scan.

You could improve the efficiency somewhat with a "covering" index on `(flag, email)`. That index would be used but only with a full index scan - you probably can't avoid that with the current design.

---

Other suggestions, some involving altering the table:

- If you can split the flags to multiple `BIT` columns, the query could be simplified and the possibility of using indexes would arise. Still, you might end up needing multiple (composite) indexes, one for each `BIT` flag.
- If the possible combinations of flags is low (as the `cardinality = 18` suggests), you could use that info in your favour by changing the condition to:

  ```
  where flag in (64, 65, 66, 68, 72, 80, ..., 192, 193, ...)
  -- the list of all possible flag values that have the proper bit set
  ```

  This might use the `(flag, email)` index slightly better than before, especially if this list is small, still scanning a small or large part of the index but not the whole index.
- A much better design would be to use an intersection (many-to-many) table to store which users have some attribute, instead of using flags.

Comment: An index on a single-bit fields is unlikely to be used.

Comment: @RickJames yes but a composite one might.